# Идентификаторы связанные с процессом

Tags: unix

Рассматриваю идентификаторы связанные с процессом, которые он наследует от того кто его запустил (очень грубо сказано конечно). Так вот, реальные ид пользователя и группы понятны - они дают инфу о том, кто запустил процесс. Дальше написано, что Эффективные ид пользователя и группы определяют правда доступа к файлам. А ещё есть сохраненные ид пользователя и группы

1. Зачем нам эффективные ид? Разве нельзя определить доступ к файлу имея только реальные ид пользователя и группы?
2. Какой посыл у Сохранённых ид?

Comment: 1. [uid vs euid](https://intelligea.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/effective-user-id-and-group-id-vs-real-user-id-and-group-id/) 2. а что это за «сохранённые»?

Comment: 2. а, понятно. см. [википедию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Saved_user_ID)